# Can the substraction of quadratic form ($(x-b)^T A(x-b)$) of two functions be written as another quadratic form plus constant

Tags: matrices, completing-the-square

A function $f: \mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is said to have quadratic form iff it can be written as $f(x)=(x-b)^T A(x-b)$ for some $A\in \mathbb R^{d\times d}$ and $b \in \mathbb R^d$. If I have two functions having quadratic forms $f(x)=(x-b_1)^T A_1(x-b_1)$ and $g(x)=(x-b_2)^T A_2(x-b_2)$ can I write $h(x):=f(x)-g(x)$ in the form of $(x-b_3)^T A_3(x-b_3) + \alpha_3$? If yes what is the explicit form of $A_3$, $\alpha$, and $b_3$ in terms of $A_1, A_2, b_1, b_2$. If no, why?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried what happens when $d=1$ or $d=2$ or $d=3$?

Comment: I expand both terms ($h(x)$ and $f(x)-g(x)$) in terms of $x^Tx$, $x$, and constant term and equate coefficient-wise. I got $A_3=A_2-A_1$, $b_3=A_3^{-1}(A_1b_1-A_2b_2)$ and $\alpha=b_1^TA_1b_1-b_2^TA_2b_2-b_3^TA_3b_3$. However, the form of $\alpha$ is a bit messy especially $b_3^TA_3b_3$ term.

Comment: Very good! What happens if $A_3$ is not invertible?

Comment: Then it cannot be done?